# Use dep to add Helm 3 as Go dependency

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, dep

I want to install Helm charts from a Go application. As suggested by the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3@v3.0.1/pkg/chartutil?tab=doc) I am loading the chart with

```
chart, err := loader.Load(filename)
```

However when trying to add this dependency with `dep ensure -add k8s.io/helm/pkg/chart/loader` I get the error:

```
Solving failure: No versions of k8s.io/helm met constraints:
        v3.0.1: unable to deduce repository and source type for "helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/ignore": unable to read metadata: unable to parse go-import metadata: XML syntax error on line 1: expected /> in element
```

How can I import this package?

Comment: What happens if you do `dep ensure -add k8s.io/helm` instead?

Comment: @Flimzy `v3.0.1: Could not introduce k8s.io/helm@v3.0.1, as its subpackage k8s.io/helm does not contain usable Go code (*build.NoGoError).. (Package is required by (root).)`